# Align the column with minus in in bmatrix

Tags: align, matrices

I am struggling with aligning the bmatrix with the minus symbol - it should look like in the picture  [image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  X_1 \\
  X_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= - \frac{1}{\xi_{11}\,\xi_{22} - \xi_{21}\,\xi_{12}}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \,\xi_{11} & \phantom{-}\xi_{12} \\
   \phantom{-}\xi_{21} & \,\xi_{22} \\  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \xi_{10} \\
  \xi_{20} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 6):

You mean like this? `bmatrix` has a starred version from `mathtools` package which accepts alignment options, here we chose `[r]`. Another solution is to use an `array` with `[rr]` alignments and manually add the brackets.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  X_1 \\
  X_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= - \frac{1}{\xi_{11}\,\xi_{22} - \xi_{21}\,\xi_{12}}
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    \xi_{11} & -\xi_{12} \\
   -\xi_{21} &  \xi_{22} \\  
\end{bmatrix*}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \xi_{10} \\
  \xi_{20} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also another choice to align your matrix with the minus symbol `-`, using `spalign` package with the option `[r]` (right). `\spaligndelims{[}{]}\spalignmat[r]{....;....}` is as a subsostitute of `bmatrix` in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[\spaligndelims{[}{]}\spalignmat[r]{X_1; X_2}=-\frac{1}{\xi_{11}\xi_{22}-\xi_{21}\xi_{12}}
\spaligndelims{[}{]}\spalignmat[r]{\xi_{11} -\xi_{12}; -\xi_{21}  \xi_{22}}\spalignmat[r]{\xi_{10} ;  \xi_{20}}\]
\end{document}
```